# Massive star evolution leading to white dwarf?

Tags: stars, stellar-evolution, white-dwarfs

Is it possible that a star with an initial mass greater than 12$M_\odot$ loses so much mass in the giant phase that it eventually becomes a white dwarf? If it is possible, what constellation or environment would be favourable for this to happen, e.g. a companion of an already present neutron star, the dense population of a globular cluster, or...?

(I rephrased the question following a comment from ProfRob.)

Comment: It isn't a probabilistic occurrence. To have a more massive progenitor you need more mass loss during the giant phase. There is no indication that 5 solar mass stars produce supernovae.